# Extract different elements from text

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a column in Google sheets that contains some text with a country code like US, JP, MX etc... somewhere in the text. I want to create another column next to it where it shows only the country code without the rest of the text.

The input looks like any of the following examples: "editing JP data", "JP data edits", "edited data for JP". The country code might be part of other data in some cases but as part of a word, not on its own...

I managed to extract the code for one country with a formula like `=REGEXEXTRACT(F2,"JP")` but I haven't managed to combine more than one regextract formulas. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "somewhere in the text" is not sufficient. Where? Separated/preceded/followed by any particular characters? Show representative sample input and desired output. All you're doing is saying "if the text contains `JP` somewhere, return `JP`, else nothing" - but what if it contains `JP` as part of other data, but that isn't actually the currency code? Etc, etc

Comment: The input looks like any of the following examples: "editing JP data", "JP data edits", "edited data for JP". The country code might be part of other data in some cases but as part of a word, not on its own...

Comment: Please [edit] your post to contain the required info; do not post it in comments.

Comment: Then you might want to search for 2 capital letters, separated by word boundaries. I am not sure how the regex impl in Google Sheets does this, but there should be documentation on how to search for N characters from set M, and how to define word boundaries (if it supports that).

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(F2:F, "JP|US|MX")))
```